# EF 5 Many-To-Many created ties correctly on update, but incorrectly on create

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have an application that uses MVC4, and EF 5. We have a `Test` object that has a navigational Many-To-Many join with `Grades` by setting up navigational properties on both sides. This created a middle Many-To-Many join table as expected.

`Test`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
```

`Grade`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
```

Due to the custom design of the application and business rules, I created a custom Model Binder for the action which takes the property `request.Form.GetValues(Grades)` as a `string[]` and adds the appropriate grades to the `test.Grades` property using the `AddRange()` method like so:

```
string[] values = request.Form.GetValues("Grades");
model.Grades.AddRange(context.Grades.Where(x => values.Contains(x.GradeLevel)).ToList();
```

This works great for an Update scenario. But if my Model Binder creates a new `Test` then the result is EF adding NEW grades to the `Grades` table, then performing the Many-To-Many join with the new grades instead of using the existing grades.

Example:

```
+-------------------+
|   Grades before   |
+--------+----------+
|GradeKey|GradeLevel|
+--------+----------+
|    1   |     K    |
|    2   |     1    |
|    3   |     2    |
|    4   |     3    |
+--------+----------+

Assume that during creation of the test only grades 1 and 2 were 
selected on the Add New Test screen    

+-------------------+
|    Grades after   |
+--------+----------+
|GradeKey|GradeLevel|
+--------+----------+
|    1   |     K    |
|    2   |     1    |
|    3   |     2    |
|    4   |     3    |
|    5   |     1    |
|    6   |     2    |
+--------+----------+
```

Then the test is joined to the new grades (with keys 5 and 6) instead of the originals (with keys 2 and 3).

Why is this behavior different with a new test vs. an existing `Test`.

*Note: I have tried this both with using `Test test = new Test();` and then assigning the properties, and also `Test test = new context.Tests.Add(new Test());`*

**Edit:**

Model binder:

```
public class TestModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        Test model;
        using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Form.Get("TestKey")))
            {
                int testkey = int.Parse(request.Form.Get("TestKey"));
                model = context.Tests.Single(x => x.TestKey == testkey);
            }
            else model = context.Tests.Add(new Test());

            ...

            if (request.Form.Get("Grades") != null)
            {

                string[] values = request.Form.GetValues("Grades");
                model.Grades = context.Grades.Where(x => values.Contains(x.GradeLevel)).ToList();
            }

            ...

        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Test test)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return PartialView("_Create", test);
    //DataService.Context.Tests.Add(test); # Removed since model is added in model binder
    DataService.Context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: How does the complete code (relevant to EF) for the Edit and Create scenario look like - from loading/attaching/creating `model` up to `SaveChanges`?

Comment: Added model binder code and controller action.

Comment: I'm wondering why anything is saved at all. You have a separate context instance in the model binder (`using (DataContext context = new DataContext())`) but don't call `SaveChanges` in *this* block but instead later in the action with `DataService.Context.SaveChanges()`. Or is `new DataContext()` somehow returning the same instance like `DataService.Context`?

Comment: No the `DataService.Context` is another instance of `DataContext`. Perhaps the `DataService.Context.Tests.Add(test);` was allowing that to work since it was still in place the last time I ran the application. I was originally only `using` the `DataContext` in the model binder so I can pull the correct `Grade` records.

Comment: Also the Model binder is used for *both* the edit and create actions

Comment: Well, the question is now difficult to answer. You are saying that the problem you describe existed with another code in the model binder than the one you are showing now. But with the model binder code right now edit *and* create will probably work if you would call `context.SaveChanges()` *inside* the `using` block.

Comment: No I'm sorry. I did not mean to use past tense in that. Every line you see has been in place and still is, except for the commented out line in the Controller that was in place the last time run. Otherwise, everything that is in my above post, still is.

Comment: My hesitance to calling `SaveChanges()` in the model binder is not only hiding the save inside of code that is hidden from the normal pattern, but also the need to check `ModelState.IsValid` to ensure the form was filled out correctly.